# Can I paste code between head and body tags?

Tags: html

Can I paste code between tags?

```
... </head> this place <body> ...
```

Comment: No you can't, very good

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Who else does that? I think it's a bad habit

Comment: Not only it's a bad habit, but it is not following the correct syntax for html files.

Comment: sir, tnx u twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser will be able to display it. But think about the purpose of HTML, it structures your web page. Pasting text between the head and body is useless and doesn't add a value to your structure.